# Why am I getting unreported exception when the super class default constructor has a 'throws' clause?

Tags: java, exception

I am getting unreported exception when I run the following the code

My code is as shown below

```
class Super {    
  public Super() throws Exception {    
    System.out.println("Super Class");    
  }    
}

public class Sub extends Super {    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    Sub s = new Sub();    
  }    
}
```

following error got:
    Sub.java:6: unreported exception java.lang.Exception in default constructor
    public class Sub extends Super {
    1 error

Answer (score 13):

You have not defined a default constructor for Sub, and Super is reporting a checked exception. To fix it add this constructor to Sub:

```
public Sub() throws Exception {
    super();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your ans,I got result

Comment: Not a big deal, but you don't need the explicit call to super() - the compiler does this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is reporting the below code and refuses to compile the code.

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

So, you have to explicitly define a constructor that does.

Answer (score 2):

All class' default constructor by default call the super class default constructor. Now as your super class constructor throws an exception, when sub-class constructor calls the super class constructor it needs to handle the exception or throw it.

Now in your class you haven't mentioned any constructor so compiler will create a default constructor and will call super(), as super() throws exception and your constructor didnt throw/handle any exception, it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jalynn2. Another solution is to make Exception to RuntimeException as you are not raising anything in particular in this constructor.

```
class Super {
  public Super() throws RuntimeException {    
    System.out.println("Super Class");    
  }
}
```